# overriding? upcasting?

Tags: c++, virtual, overriding

The following code has the bug: last line should be
`bp->g();`
The question is, if I comment out that line, `bp->f()` actually calls the Derived version, So I assume the compiler treat bp as class Derived, then why when call g, the compiler treat `bp` as *Base pointer.*

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    virtual void f() const { cout << "Base::f()\n"<< endl; }
    virtual void g() const { cout << "Base::g()\n"<< endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void f() const {cout << "Derived::f()" << endl; }
    void g(int) const {cout << "Derived::g()" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    Base* bp = new Derived;
    bp->f();
    bp->g(1);
}
```

Comment: In Drived class `void g(int ??)` variable name missing.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan the variable is not used, so no name is needed.

Comment: @juanchopanza ok I just noticed

Comment: You can only call methods in the public interface of `Base` from a pointer to `Base`, but the calls get dispatched to the derived type.

Answer (score 4):

You can't override a virtual member function by changing its arguments. That is, `Derived::g(int)` is *not* overriding `Base::g()`.

Imagine you are the compiler. You see the function call `bp->g(1)` and you know that `bp` is a `Base*`. So you look up `Base` for a function called `g` that takes an argument that is an `int`. What do you find? Nothing! There isn't one.

It's only when a function is found in the base class to be virtual that it will then consider the dynamic type of the object. So let's consider the call `bp->f()`. It knows that `bp` is a `Base*`, so it looks up a member function of `Base` called `f` that takes no arguments. It finds `Base::f()` of course, and sees that it is virtual. Because it is virtual, it then looks up the same function in the dynamic type of the object, which is `Derived`. It finds `Derived::f()` and calls that one instead.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `Derived::g` does not override `Base::g`. It is a completely independent method that happens to have the same name. The two methods are unrelated because they take different arguments.

Thus when you call `bp->g(1)`, the fact that `Base` also happens to have a method called `g` is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

your Derived class now doesn't override the `Base::g()`:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
//...
    void f() const {cout << "Derived::f()" << endl; }
    void g() const {cout << "Derived::g()" << endl; } // <- add this, it is overriding Base::g() const
//...
};
```

the method:  `void g(int) const {cout << "Derived::g()" << endl; }` is autonomic method of your Derived class, it doesn't override `Base::g` because none of `Base::g` takes `int` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your sample should give compile time error in line
bp->g(1);
In both cases compiler treats bp as Base* having 2 virtual functions void f() and void g() with f() overridden in Derived thus when you call bp->f(), Derived version will be called via vtable. But there is no void g(int) in Base, thus bp->g(1) would lead to compile time error.